# Collapsible fieldsets in Foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation, fieldset

I want to create collapsible fieldsets using just [Foundation 5](http://foundation.zurb.com/). I found [this](http://michael.theirwinfamily.net/articles/jquery/collapsible-fieldsets-jquery-plugin-drupal-style), done with jQuery.

**Is there any Foundation-based plugin to create collapsible fieldsets?**

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use accordion from the http://madmimi.github.io/angular-foundation/

Comment: Nice! That library was my first option, but I couldn't make it work. Now, I realized I wasn't including the needed files properly. Your link drove me to the solution. Many thanks.

Comment: @jorgeas80 +1 for the story :)